# Question about HSQL DB in memory database

Tags: database, memory, hsqldb

I have created a memory-only server instance of hsqldb , is it possible for me to connect to this memory database from 2 clients in separate jvms ?

Answer (score 3):

Let me see if I understand your point: but starting your HSQLDB you can consider as a normal DataBase, like MySQL/PostgreSQL.

If you have the driver/IP/port/user/passwd to connect to your HSQLBD you can put any 'client' communicating with your database.

I know that its not my application, but remembering that HSQLDB is *normally* used for **test purpose**. Have some **limitations** *"Number of columns, tables, indexes, size of columns and so on is limited only by the memory"*

Nice to read: http://hsqldb.org/doc/guide/index.html

Cheers